# Prevent click event on menu item from reloading in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using ASP Menu control with a collection of sub menu items. If user clicks on main menu item it reloads and the screen makes a postback. It irritates the user when clicks on main menu as it is only to list out the categories. How to prevent the loading of page when user clicks on main menu item I tried some code using javascript but its not working.

My ASP menu control:

```
<asp:Menu ID="mini" OnMenuItemClick="mini_MenuItemClick" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Items">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="sdaad" Value="1" >
                <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub1"  Value="MenuSub1" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub2" Value="MenuSub2" ></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="qwerty" Value="qwerty">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Javascript to handle the issue:

```
function OnMenuItemClick(s, e) {
    if (e.item.name == "Items")
        e.processOnServer = false;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at asp:updatepanel

Comment: Can you please briefly explain it

Answer (score 1):

First, put update panel in markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Update" UpdateModel="Conditional">
</UpdatePanel>
```

Then use javascript to trigger it:

```
__doPostBack(<%# Update.ClientID%>, '');
```

Comment: Where should I add java script code and update control. Sorry I am new to asp.net

Comment: `The control with ID 'Update' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.`

Comment: Then add <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"/>

Comment: Now javascript code is not working  `<script type="text/javascript">
       _doPostBack(<%# Update.ClientID%>, 'Items');</script>`

Comment: Now I got this error `The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).`